# DateTime Format

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, string-formatting

Currently I am using below code to get `March 06`.  What do I do to get `06 March`?

```
Text='<%# Bind("ToDate","{0:m}")%>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hzz3aycd(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Either use a custom format string or use a different locale.  If I'm reading the code right, here's a format string to give you the right string:

```
Text='<%# Bind("ToDate", "{0:dd MMMM}") %>'
```

I'm not sure how you'd use a different locale however.  Someone else might have the answer to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
Text='<%# Bind("ToDate","{0:dd MMM}")%>'
```